# How to restore a Bitmap after erasing a part of it, while preserving its alpha?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, porter-duff

I am working on an android application which has 2 features:-

1. is to remove(erase) a part of the image for a given path, just like the eraser
   in photoshop.
2. is to restore the image for a given path.

I've implemented the erasing part

```
mEraserPaint = new Paint(1);
mEraserPaint.setDither(true);
mEraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mEraserPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
mEraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
mEraserPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mEraserPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mEraserPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mEraserPaint.setStrokeWidth(this.strokeWidth);
mEditingCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mEraserPaint);
```

And, the repair feature like,

```
mRepairPaint = new Paint(1);
mRepairPaint.setDither(true);
mRepairPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mRepairPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
mRepairPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mRepairPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mRepairPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mRepairPaint.setStrokeWidth(this.strokeWidth);



mRepairPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOriginalBitmap.getWidth(),
                        mOriginalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mRepairPaint);
mRepairPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(mOriginalBitmap, 0, 0, mRepairPaint);
mRepairPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
mEditingCanvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, mRepairPaint);
```

The problem is that, in the repair feature alpha of the image is not preserved and the image is drawn with full opacity. I need to preserve the alpha of image.

So, I need to know how to repair an image after erasing a part of it, while preserving its alpha.

Comment: What format are you saving the repaired image in?

Comment: Image can be of any format on the disk, when I retrieve in my app it is converted into a Bitmap in memory